# Polars Python write_csv error: "pyo3_runtime.PanicException: should not be here"

Tags: python-polars

I am new to using Polars for Python. I am taking a dataframe as an input, converting each column to a numpy array, reassigning values to certain indices in these arrays, deleting specific rows from all of these arrays, and then converting each array to a dataframe and performing a pl.concat (horizontally) on these dataframes. I know that the operation is working because I am able to print the dataframe on Terminal. However, when I try to write the outputDF to a csv file, I get the error below. Any help fixing the error would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.: Here is the link to the sample input data:
https://mega.nz/file/u0Z0GS6b#uSD6PDqyHXIEfWDLNQR2VgaqBcBSgeLdSL8lSjTSq3M

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'should not be here', /Users/runner/work/polars/polars/polars/polars-core/src/chunked_array/ops/any_value.rs:103:32
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/my_code/segmentation/gpt3_embeddings.py", line 89, in <module>
    result = process_data(df)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/my_code/segmentation/gpt3_embeddings.py", line 80, in process_data
    outputDF.write_csv("PostProcessing_output.csv")
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/segmentation/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py", line 2033, in write_csv
    self._df.write_csv(
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: should not be here
```

My code looks as follows:

```
# PROCESSING THE TRANSCRIBED TEXT:'
def process_data(inputDF):
    # Convert relevant columns in the dataframe to numpy arrays
    phraseArray = inputDF["phrase"].to_numpy()
    actorArray = inputDF["actor"].to_numpy()
    startTimeArray = inputDF["start_time"].to_numpy()
    endTimeArray = inputDF["end_time"].to_numpy()

    # get indicators marking where two consecutive rows have the same actor
    speaker_change = inputDF.select(pl.col("actor").diff())
    speaker_change = speaker_change.rename({"actor": "change"})
    inputDF = inputDF.with_column(speaker_change.to_series(0))
    zero_indices = inputDF.filter(pl.col("change") == 0).select(["sentence_index"]).to_series().to_list() # indices where diff() gave 0
    if len(zero_indices) > 0:
        for index in reversed(zero_indices):
            extract_phrase = phraseArray[index]
            extract_endTime = endTimeArray[index]
            joined_phrases = phraseArray[index - 1] + extract_phrase
            phraseArray[index - 1] = joined_phrases
            endTimeArray[index - 1] = extract_endTime
            phraseArray = np.delete(phraseArray, index)
            actorArray = np.delete(actorArray, index)
            startTimeArray = np.delete(startTimeArray, index)
            endTimeArray = np.delete(endTimeArray, index)
        outputDF = pl.concat([pl.DataFrame(actorArray, columns=["actor"], orient="col"), pl.DataFrame(phraseArray, columns=["phrase"], orient="col"), pl.DataFrame(startTimeArray, columns=["start_time"], orient="col"), pl.DataFrame(endTimeArray, columns=["end_time"], orient="col")], rechunk=True, how="horizontal")
        outputDF = outputDF.with_row_count(name="sentence_index")
        outputDF = outputDF[["sentence_index", "actor", "phrase", "start_time", "end_time"]]
        print(outputDF[342:348])
        outputDF.write_csv("PostProcessing_output.csv")
        return outputDF
    else:
        return inputDF
```

I tried using df.hstack instead of concat but that did not work either. I also tried rechunk on the dataframe but that did not help either. I think the issue has to do with me converting the columns into numpy arrays and then converting them back to dataframes, but I am not sure.

Comment: Please make a minimal example with the input data you are using.

Comment: To add to @ritchie46's comment.  The difficulty in helping you translate your code to pure polars is many orders of magnitude higher without sample data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ritchie46 Thanks for your comment. I have added a link to sample data in the post. Here it is: https://mega.nz/file/u0Z0GS6b#uSD6PDqyHXIEfWDLNQR2VgaqBcBSgeLdSL8lSjTSq3M

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Thanks for your comment. Here is the data: https://mega.nz/file/u0Z0GS6b#uSD6PDqyHXIEfWDLNQR2VgaqBcBSgeLdSL8lSjTSq3M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to group consecutive rows based on the actor column and "combine" them.

A common approach to this is to create "group ids" using the `.cumsum()` of comparing inequality to the previous row:

```
>>> df.head(8).with_columns((pl.col("actor") != pl.col("actor").shift()).cumsum().alias("id"))
shape: (8, 6)
┌────────────────┬───────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┬─────┐
│ sentence_index | actor | phrase                              | start_time     | end_time       | id  │
│ ---            | ---   | ---                                 | ---            | ---            | --- │
│ str            | str   | str                                 | str            | str            | u32 │
╞════════════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╪═════╡
│ 0              | 1     |  companies. So I don't have any ... | 0:00:00        | 0:00:28.125000 | 1   │
├────────────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────┤
│ 1              | 0     |  Oh yeah, that's fine.              | 0:00:28.125000 | 0:00:29.625000 | 2   │
├────────────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────┤
│ 2              | 1     |  Okay, good. And so I have a few... | 0:00:29.625000 | 0:00:38.625000 | 3   │
├────────────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────┤
│ 3              | 0     |  I'm in the parking lot, yeah? Y... | 0:00:38.625000 | 0:00:41.375000 | 4   │
├────────────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────┤
│ 4              | 1     |  Thank you.                         | 0:00:41.375000 | 0:00:42.125000 | 5   │
├────────────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────┤
│ 5              | 1     |  And so when we get ready for th... | 0:00:42.375000 | 0:01:44.125000 | 5   │
├────────────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────┤
│ 6              | 0     |  Yeah, let's just get started.      | 0:01:44.125000 | 0:01:45.375000 | 6   │
├────────────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────┤
│ 7              | 1     |  Okay, let's do it. So first of ... | 0:01:45.375000 | 0:01:52.625000 | 7   │
└────────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┴─────┘
```

Note that rows with sentence_index `4` and `5` end up with the same `id` - this can be used to `.groupby()`

- It looks like you want the `.last()` end_time
- `.str.concat()` can be used to "combine" the phrase values
- `.first()` can be used for the remaining columns

```
output_df = (
   df.groupby((pl.col("actor") != pl.col("actor").shift()).cumsum().alias("id")).agg([
      pl.col("actor").first(),
      pl.col("sentence_index").first(),
      pl.col("phrase").str.concat(delimiter=""),
      pl.col("start_time").first(),
      pl.col("end_time").last()
   ])
   .sort("sentence_index")
   .drop(["id", "sentence_index"])
   .with_row_count("sentence_index")
)
```

Comment: Wow this seems to have worked! I can write the output_df to a csv finally without getting the error I mentioned. I am still not sure why my solution was triggering that error despite printing on the terminal screen but your solution didn't just solve the problem but also looks so much more compact and elegant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your code gives me a different error `the offset of the new Buffer cannot exceed the existing length`. The error goes away if I convert the arrays to lists after modification: `pl.DataFrame([actorArray.tolist(), phraseArray.tolist(), startTimeArray.tolist(), endTimeArray.tolist()]).with_row_count().write_csv()` which suggests `np.delete()` may be the problem. But you're not really using polars by converting things to numpy arrays and then manually rebuilding a dataframe - so it was simpler for me to show how it may be done inside polars.